# How to merge multiple xlsx files into one single xlsx file with different sheets by openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I would like to merge several `xlsx` files from list into one so that each `sheet` has the `name` of the next merged file. Single `xlsx` files have one `sheet` with `data` stored in columns and rows. To create single files I am using `openpyxl` library.

```
xlsx_files = ['u_gen_inf.xlsx', 'u_dates_inf.xlsx', 'u_ctrl_inf.xlsx']
```

loop I would like to create

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook, Workbook

for f in xlsx_files:
    ? load_workbook() - universal code independent of the number of xlsx files

wb_master.save('master_users_inf.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, you just need to implement (inside your `for` loop) [`create_sheet`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/openpyxl.workbook.workbook.html?highlight=create_sheet#openpyxl.workbook.workbook.Workbook.create_sheet) to create a new sheet in the master file and then use [`iter_rows`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html?highlight=iter_rows#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.iter_rows) to grab all the values from all the rows.

Here is a proposition (*without your comments to make a short code*) :

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook, Workbook

wb_master = Workbook()

xlsx_files = ['u_gen_inf.xlsx', 'u_dates_inf.xlsx', 'u_ctrl_inf.xlsx']

for f in xlsx_files:
    sub_wb = load_workbook(f)
    sub_ws = sub_wb.active
    
    wb_master_sheet = wb_master.create_sheet(sub_ws.title)
    
    for row in sub_ws.iter_rows():
        for cell in row:
            wb_master_sheet[cell.coordinate].value = cell.value
    
   #wb_master_sheet.column_dimensions["A"].width = 20 #uncomment this line to set a width    

wb_master.remove_sheet("Sheet") #or del wb_master["Sheet"] 
wb_master.save('master_users_inf.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I added `del wb master['Sheet']` before saving because it was creating the first sheet named `Sheet`

Comment: I have one more question, in `xlsx` files I use `ws.column_dimensions['A'].width = 20`, where in the code and how to assign such settings so that columns in sheets have either copied settings or made a new?

Comment: If you need to do that to all the worksheets of the master file, you need to insert such statements in the first loop. I updated my answer to show you where exactly.

Comment: ok but this only changes column A in all sheets, what about the rest of the columns? e.g. column B in users_dates_inf has a width of 13 because there is a date YYYY-MM-DD and the same column in users_controls_inf has 5 because there is a value of 0 or 1.

Comment: I read about getting the length of a value from a cell and if I am thinking correctly I need another nested for loop in the second, which will read the length of the values in the cells, but from the second (the first are titles) row down and adjust the width to the longest value

Comment: Maybe this is the subject of a separate question ?